# How can I describe an element with some ANY child element and some known?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I describe the "content" element in a schema file such that the order of the children is know but after "metadata" and before "content-section" any elements may placed?

Basically I want to do what is described in the example below. This, of coarse, will not work. I would 1 or more elements to be placed in the location where  is currently.

```
<xs:element name="content">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence> 
       <xs:element name="metadata" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></<xs:element>
       <xs:any>
       <xs:element name="content-section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">/<xs:element>  
       <xs:element name="content-footer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   </<xs:element>    
 </xs:element>
```

XML:

```
  <content>
    <metadata></metadata>
    <h1>Not in schema</h1>
    <p>also not in schema</p>
    <content-section></content-section>
    <content-footer></content-footer>
  </content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems you may run into is called Unique Particle attribution. It all depends on what namespaces those `any` elements you want may be part of.

Worst case scenario is any namespace. So, taking on your requirement (unlike InfantPro'Aravind' which navigated around the issue by prescribing content-section to be mandatory where you wanted it optional, and limited the maxOccurs of your any element to an arbitrary number) this is where we start from (**BAD schema, violates UPA**). First, fix any's maxOccurs to allow for `1 or more elements to be placed in the location`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="content">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="metadata" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="content-section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="content-footer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Error is:

```
Error occurred while loading [how-can-i-describe-an-element-with-some-any-child-element-and-some-known.xsd], line 8 position 6.
Wildcard '##any' allows element 'metadata', and causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.
```

Now you need to fix this. These are your options:

1) restrict the namespace of any to something else (e.g. ##other):

```
<xsd:any maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other"/>
```

If you can't restrict your namespaces, these are your options:

2) Wrap the `any` content into another element (called Extension):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="content">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="metadata" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="extension"/>
                <xsd:element name="content-section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="content-footer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

All others involve moving the `any` content at the bottom.

3) Move your `any` right at the bottom, and precede it with a mandatory element.

If you want this type global and allow it not be final, then you get into other patterns.

Comment: nicely explained .. I think I should have given similar explanation than showing over-usage of `any` :P

Comment: Awesome! I ended up adding another element. Option 2. Thanks for the through answer!

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `Any` with `processContents="skip"` works in your way..

I am picking up a better example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <metadata></metadata>
  <h1>Not in schema</h1>
  <p>also not in schema</p>
  <content-section></content-section>
  <content-footer>Do not validate this as well</content-footer>
</content>
```

And the relevant XSD for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="content" type="content"/>
  <xs:complexType name="content">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>
      <xs:element name="content-section"  type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```